# MATLAB sliding window over non-zero values only

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering

I have an image processing task where I've used a mask to segment an image. The next step is to extract features using certain convolutional filters. However, I don't want to a) waste time processing the black (all 0's) background, or b) have distorted edge cases. I have a filter algorithm that handles edges the way I need, but I don't want the have to deal with all the padded zeroes.

How can I apply this filter to only the non-zero pixels in the matrix? I was thinking something in the same style as [cellfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) where you apply a function to cells using function handles, but I can't make it work for this task.

I am working with 2D convolutions on a grayscale 2D matrix.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Mathematically, what would the difference be between zeros and ignoring zeros? I would assume this would really depend on your filter kernel. For example if your kernel was `ones(n)/n` then the extra zeros would reduce your result *iff* you actually wanted to reduce `n` to only reflect the number of non zeros in each window, i.e. your filter would be dynamic. I doubt there is a general solution to your problem and that you will have to be specific about your filtering operations...

Comment: Well for one it's a high-res image that has been extracted using a binary mask. As a result I have something like a 1500x1500 image with only a 700x800 object in the middle, all else are 0's. I don't want to crop down because I'll have to pad again later (for homogeneity across my dataset). Also, because I'm using a variety of patch sizes, I sometime get skewed data for some of my features (for example gradient and variance).

Comment: So you want to apply a mask (2D-convolution) only to non-zero pixels. Correct? And is your image BW (2D array) or colour (3D array)?

Comment: So you don't want to ignore zeros near the actual image, just the padding zero in order to save time? So firstly I would say the 1500 by 1500 doesn't sound very big, have you tried just running the filter over the whole image? Is it really too slow? If it is, then I guess you could find the area of the image you would have cropped, and just run your convolution over that portion (using good old subscript indexing) and then you won't have to worry about padding the image

Comment: @Dan 1500x1500 isn't too big but I have hundreds of images to process multiple times over. I've used subscript indexing before, but never with a sliding window filter. How would that work in these circumstances?

Comment: @LuisMendo - I edited the post to answer your question. Thanks for requesting clarification

Comment: `conv2` won't let you specify the domain. You could use two nested `for` loops and do the convolution manually, but it will probably be slower. Maybe you could do the whole convolution but speed it up in some other way. Is your filter [separable](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/04/separable-convolution/)?